# Some Prisma Model @@map not generating

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql, prisma

I have a few models in my schema.prisma file that are not generating with their @@map for use in the client.

```
model ContentFilter {
  id                Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  blurriness        Float?        @default(0.3)
  adult             Float?        @default(0.5)
  medical           Float?        @default(0.8)
  violence          Float?        @default(0.5)
  racy              Float?        @default(0.5)
  party_settings_id Int           @unique
  party_settings    PartySettings @relation(fields: [party_settings_id], references: [id])

  @@map("contentfilter")
}

model PartySettings {
  id                 Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  start              DateTime?      @default(now())
  end                DateTime?      @default(now())
  require_location   Boolean?       @default(false)
  require_name       Boolean?       @default(true)
  allow_comments     Boolean?       @default(true)
  allow_likes        Boolean?       @default(true)
  allow_before_party Boolean?       @default(false)
  party_id           Int            @unique
  party              Party          @relation(fields: [party_id], references: [id])
  content_filter     ContentFilter?

  @@map("partysettings")
}

model Party {
  id          Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  hash        String         @unique
  description String
  user_id     Int
  user        User           @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  images      Image[]
  order       Order?
  settings    PartySettings?

  @@map("party")
}
```

the rest of my models are available in the client by referencing them with prisma.mappedname
such as prisma.party (from the example above) that table is exposed and available within the client. But both the partysettings and contentfilter is not avialable. I've ran the migrate and generate commands many times as well as deleted my database and reran migrate and generate.
Could anyone help me understand what i'm doing so different in these two tables?

Answer (score 0):

`@@map` operator is used to declare the table name in the database, it doesn't affect the model names that are generated via `PrismaClient`.

So as per your schema file, the name of the tables in your database would be `party`, `contentfilter` and `partysettings`.

By default the name of the property is the lowercase form of the model name, e.g. `user` for a `User` model or `post` for a `Post` model.

Map attribute: [Reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#map-1)